# Problem with StreamBuilder when put the asBroadcastStream method

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem working with Flutter and MySql, the problem is that I want it to be an asynchronous application, but I dont know how and I have being use FutureBuilder but I read that I can use StreamBuilder, The problem with StreamBuilder is that when you put the asBroadcastStream method, load the data only once but then stay listen without loading anything Sorry if my english isn't good

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final userName;

  const Home({Key key, this.userName}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

  var stData = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20,
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal
  );

  var stcols = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20,
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
  );

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  TabController _tabController;

  Future<List> _getData() async{
    final response = await http.post('http://michelle-gonzalez.000webhostapp.com/escuela/solicitud.php');
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  Future<List>getPendientes() async{
    final response = await http.post('http://michelle-gonzalez.000webhostapp.com/escuela/pendientes.php', body: {
      'encargado': widget.userName,
    });
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Nombre de Usuario: '+widget.userName);
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(230, 230, 230, 1),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(20, 81, 171, 1),
          title: Text('Administrador'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 160,
                child:Tab(
                  text: 'Entrada',
                  icon: Icon(Icons.email),
                )
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160,
                child:Tab(
                  text: 'Pendientes',
                  icon: Icon(Icons.email),
                )
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
                StreamBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                  stream: Stream.fromFuture(_getData()).asBroadcastStream(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                    if(snapshot.hasError)print(snapshot.error);

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final userName;

  const Home({Key key, this.userName}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

  var stData = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20,
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal
  );

  var stcols = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20,
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
  );

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Future<List> asd;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState((){});
  }

  TabController _tabController;

  Future<List> _getData() async{
    final response = await http.post('http://michelle-gonzalez.000webhostapp.com/escuela/solicitud.php');
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  Future<List>getPendientes() async{
    final response = await http.post('http://michelle-gonzalez.000webhostapp.com/escuela/pendientes.php', body: {
      'encargado': widget.userName,
    });
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Nombre de Usuario: '+widget.userName);
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(230, 230, 230, 1),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(20, 81, 171, 1),
          title: Text('Administrador'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 160,
                child:Tab(
                  text: 'Entrada',
                  icon: Icon(Icons.email),
                )
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160,
                child:Tab(
                  text: 'Pendientes',
                  icon: Icon(Icons.email),
                )
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
                StreamBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                  stream: Stream.fromFuture(_getData()).asBroadcastStream(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                    if(snapshot.hasError)print(snapshot.error);

                    return snapshot.hasData? 
                    ListView(
                      children:
                        snapshot.data.map(
                        (element)=> Card(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 400,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(6), topRight: Radius.circular(6)),
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(234, 108, 126, 1),
                                  ),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text('#${element['ticket']}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 28),),
                                      Text(element['nombre'], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 28),),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ),
                                DataTable(
                                  columnSpacing: 3,
                                  columns: <DataColumn>[
                                    DataColumn(label: Text('Departamento', style: stcols,)),
                                    DataColumn(label: Text(element['departamento'], style: stData,))
                                  ],
                                  rows: <DataRow>[
                                    DataRow(
                                      cells:<DataCell>[
                                        DataCell(Text('Correo', style: stcols,)),
                                        DataCell(Container(
                                          width: 200,
                                          height: 60,
                                          child: Text(element['correo'], style: stData,),
                                        ))
                                      ]
                                    ),
                                    DataRow(
                                      cells:<DataCell>[
                                        DataCell(Text('Falla', style: stcols,)),
                                        DataCell(GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: (){
                                            // numTicket = widget.lista[i]['ticket'];
                                            // _showFalla();
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: 200,
                                            height: 60,
                                            child: Text(element['falla'], style: stData,),
                                          ),
                                        ))
                                      ]
                                    ),
                                    DataRow(
                                      cells:<DataCell>[
                                        DataCell(Text('Fecha', style: stcols,)),
                                        DataCell(Text(element['fecha'], style: stData,))
                                      ]
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50,right: 40,left: 40),
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    onPressed: (){
                                      // numTicket = widget.lista[i]['ticket'];
                                      // _atender();
                                    },
                                    child: Text('Atender', style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      letterSpacing: 2
                                    ),),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        )
                      ).toList(),
                    )
                    : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                  },
                )
            ,
            Text('data')
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}                    return snapshot.hasData? 
                    ListView(
                      children:
                        snapshot.data.map(
                        (element)=> Card(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 400,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(6), topRight: Radius.circular(6)),
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(234, 108, 126, 1),
                                  ),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text('#${element['ticket']}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 28),),
                                      Text(element['nombre'], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 28),),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ),
                                DataTable(
                                  columnSpacing: 3,
                                  columns: <DataColumn>[
                                    DataColumn(label: Text('Departamento', style: stcols,)),
                                    DataColumn(label: Text(element['departamento'], style: stData,))
                                  ],
                                  rows: <DataRow>[
                                    DataRow(
                                      cells:<DataCell>[
                                        DataCell(Text('Correo', style: stcols,)),
                                        DataCell(Container(
                                          width: 200,
                                          height: 60,
                                          child: Text(element['correo'], style: stData,),
                                        ))
                                      ]
                                    ),
                                    DataRow(
                                      cells:<DataCell>[
                                        DataCell(Text('Falla', style: stcols,)),
                                        DataCell(GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: (){
                                            // numTicket = widget.lista[i]['ticket'];
                                            // _showFalla();
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: 200,
                                            height: 60,
                                            child: Text(element['falla'], style: stData,),
                                          ),
                                        ))
                                      ]
                                    ),
                                    DataRow(
                                      cells:<DataCell>[
                                        DataCell(Text('Fecha', style: stcols,)),
                                        DataCell(Text(element['fecha'], style: stData,))
                                      ]
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50,right: 40,left: 40),
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    onPressed: (){
                                      // numTicket = widget.lista[i]['ticket'];
                                      // _atender();
                                    },
                                    child: Text('Atender', style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      letterSpacing: 2
                                    ),),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        )
                      ).toList(),
                    )
                    : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                  },
                )
            ,
            Text('data')
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Nombre de Usuario: '+widget.userName);
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(230, 230, 230, 1),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(20, 81, 171, 1),
          title: Text('Administrador'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 160,
                child:Tab(
                  text: 'Entrada',
                  icon: Icon(Icons.email),
                )
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160,
                child:Tab(
                  text: 'Pendientes',
                  icon: Icon(Icons.email),
                )
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
                StreamBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                  stream: Stream.fromFuture(_getData()).asBroadcastStream(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                    if(snapshot.hasError)print(snapshot.error);

                    return snapshot.hasData? 
                    ListView(
                      children:
                        snapshot.data.map(
                        (element)=> Card(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 400,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(6), topRight: Radius.circular(6)),
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(234, 108, 126, 1),
                                  ),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text('#${element['ticket']}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 28),),
                                      Text(element['nombre'], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 28),),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ),
                                DataTable(
                                  columnSpacing: 3,
                                  columns: <DataColumn>[
                                    DataColumn(label: Text('Departamento', style: stcols,)),
                                    DataColumn(label: Text(element['departamento'], style: stData,))
                                  ],
                                  rows: <DataRow>[
                                    DataRow(
                                      cells:<DataCell>[
                                        DataCell(Text('Correo', style: stcols,)),
                                        DataCell(Container(
                                          width: 200,
                                          height: 60,
                                          child: Text(element['correo'], style: stData,),
                                        ))
                                      ]
                                    ),
                                    DataRow(
                                      cells:<DataCell>[
                                        DataCell(Text('Falla', style: stcols,)),
                                        DataCell(GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: (){
                                            // numTicket = widget.lista[i]['ticket'];
                                            // _showFalla();
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: 200,
                                            height: 60,
                                            child: Text(element['falla'], style: stData,),
                                          ),
                                        ))
                                      ]
                                    ),
                                    DataRow(
                                      cells:<DataCell>[
                                        DataCell(Text('Fecha', style: stcols,)),
                                        DataCell(Text(element['fecha'], style: stData,))
                                      ]
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50,right: 40,left: 40),
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    onPressed: (){
                                      // numTicket = widget.lista[i]['ticket'];
                                      // _atender();
                                    },
                                    child: Text('Atender', style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      letterSpacing: 2
                                    ),),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        )
                      ).toList(),
                    )
                    : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                  },
                )
            ,
            Text('data')
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "no hablamos" - we speak here - sorry

Comment: This is an **English-only** site - please post in English, or otherwise please post on https://en.stackoverflow.com in Spanish

Comment: I have a problem working with Flutter and MySql, the problem is that I want it to be an asynchronous application, but I dont know how and I have being use FutureBuilder but I read that I can use StreamBuilder, The problem with StreamBuilder is that when you put the asBroadcastStream method, load the data only once but then stay listen without loading anything

Sorry if my english isn't good